# Diseño de una base de datos de cursos para relacionar cursos de una universidad con alumnosn que los reciben

Tags: sql

Un departamento de la universidad ofrece 5 cursos. Tengo una lista con los institutos de origen de los alumnos y sé cuántos alumnos de determinado instituto toman los cursos en cuestión.

Sé como crear la tabla de los cursos y la tabla de los institutos pero, ¿cómo uno las 2 tablas?

Por ejemplo, sé que el instituto 1 envía 2 alumnos al curso A, 1 al B, y 0 a los demás. Sé como enlazar esta información con los institutos pero ¿y con los cursos?

Comment: publica tu sql, y te ayudaremos con tus avances

Comment: Tengo la tabla de las escuelas con un ID, nombre de la escuela y teléfono.
La tabla de los cursos de la uni con un ID, nombre del curso y nombre del profesor.

Y sé cuantos estudiantes de x escuela estan en cada curso pero no sé como crear esta tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso el cual no tengas información de los alumnos, sino simplemente el número de alumnos, necesitas una tabla donde se recoja el **número de alumnos** de **qué instituto** van a **qué curso**

Te pongo la consulta para crear la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE inscripciones (
    id_escuela int, 
    id_curso int, 
    alumnos int NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT inscripciones_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_escuela, id_curso), 
    CONSTRAINT inscripciones_escuela_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_escuela) REFERENCES escuelas (ID), 
    CONSTRAINT inscripciones_curso_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_curso) REFERENCES cursos (ID)
)
```

**Nota:** *tendrás que adaptar un poco los tipos de los campos para que se ajusten al tipo de la columna a la que referencian*

Comment: Es lo que he hecho, hablé con el profesor y malinterpreté la tabla, pensaba que la teníamos que utilizar tal y como se presentaba pero se tiene que adaptar.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: Amigos, debe ser FOREIGN no FOREING.

Answer (score 1):

Debe crear un modelo de datos. Es decir crear las tablas y relacionarlas por claves primarias y foraneas.
Este link Puede ayudarle a entender como se hace esto.
http://www.aulaclic.es/sqlserver/secuencias/p01_relaciones.htm

Una vez creadas las relaciones entre tablas de su base de datos puede usar el SQL para recuperar la información según las relaciones creadas.
Este link quizás le sea útil:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

Answer (score 0):

La información del problema es escasa, podrías publicar tu SQL o tu E/R para ayudarte con mayor precisión.

Pero si tu problema son las relaciones algo así te podría ayudar. Según lo que publicas la base de datos podría quedar algo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que no sé como crear el EAR...
Tengo una tabla con los cursos de la universidad (ID, nombre, profesor), una tabla con los institutos que envían sus estudiantes a la universidad (ID, nombre, teléfono)

Y luego sé el número de estudiantes de cada instituto de orígen que hay en cada curso. Y aquí es donde tengo el problema.